# retriving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-image

i have data where there is image post and description 
when i retrieve the data it shows error toast, 
can't find whats wrong here is my code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("post")
    var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    private val TAG = ""
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.DrawerId)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false)
         val users = ArrayList<RecyClass>()
         val userlist = ArrayList<RecyClass>()

         ref.addChildEventListener(object :ChildEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
                    Log.e(TAG ,"Error is here")
                }
                override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}
                override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}
                override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
                    if(p0!!.exists()){
                        for (h in p0.children) {
                        getpost(h.key)


                        }

                    }
                }
                override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {}
            })



    }

    private fun getpost(key: String?) { 
        val postdata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("post").child(key)
        postdata.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            }
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                if(p0!!.exists()){
          val userlist = ArrayList<RecyClass>()
                 var descText = ""
                 var Image = ""
                 if (p0.child("desc").getValue()!=null){
 descText = p0.child(key).child("desc").getValue().toString()
               }
                if (p0.child("Image").getValue()!=null){
                     Image = p0.child(key).child("Image").getValue().toString()
                }
              val kkk = RecyClass(descText,Image)
                val adptr =RecyclerAdapter(userlist,applicationContext )
                  userlist.add(kkk)

                 adptr.notifyDataSetChanged()
             }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

        }
        })
    }
```

i already have multiple data inside firebase node
when i put toast inside if(p0!!.exists()) it shows but when toast is moved inside if (p0.child("desc").getValue()!=null) it dhoesnt work..

i am getting blank page in recycler view

Comment: You didn't put the Toast message inside the P0!!.exists(())..rather you put Outside of it.I think,since you didn't change the data it executes the else clause..(that is the error toast message)

Comment: and data does not populate in recyclerview..